# Denormalizing path separator in Node.js under Windows

Tags: node.js, path

In Windows, `path` module of Node.js produces all paths with backslash. It seems like it calls its own `normalize()` function when other functions (like `resolve()`) are called.

Is there a way to *de-normalize* the paths (with forward slash), without explicit replacement all over the place?

I tried setting `path.sep = '/'`, but `resolve()` still produces paths with `\\`.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is possible.  What's your use-case?  We might be able to come up with a better solution given the big picture.

Comment: Use case is to get the path of assets, relative to another path (page). So the resultant path when appears in `<a href=` will be this relative path. Besides, any network accessible path uses forward slash, so it must be a common requirement for Windows users.

Comment: Ah, you're looking to build URLs rather than native file paths.  Does the `url` module do what you're looking for?  See [url.resolve](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_resolve_from_to).  Are there other functions from `path` that you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can [`path.sep`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep) or `path.parse` to disassemble path and then join it as you like.

Comment: (path.delimiter is to separate paths (the colon in `/usr/bin:/bin`). You meant sep.)

Comment: `path.parse` is what helped me escape the `multer` path escaping.... Thanks!

Answer (score -6):

I had that problem with Windows 10. I resolved it with this script:

```
var path = require('path');

path.join2 = path.join;
path.sep = '/';
path.join = function(){
    var res = path.join2.apply({}, arguments);
    res = res.replace(/\\/g, path.sep);
    return res;
}
//rest of your code
```

Comment: Please do not advise people to monkey-patch the standard library.